# High ping every 10 seconds on Windows when using LightScreen

Tags: wireless-networking, ping

I'm on Windows 10. My wifi network is experiencing high ping every 10 seconds. For example, here I am pinging my router:

```
ping 192.168.10.1 -t

Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=1215ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=1036ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=763ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.1: bytes=32 time=581ms TTL=64
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of an app that I used to take screenshot called LightScreen. It uses a library called Qt and this library has a bug with its network manager where it does a wifi network poll every 10 seconds and causes network disruption:

https://github.com/ckaiser/Lightscreen/blob/master/tools/uploader/uploader.cpp#L30

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40332

This can be fixed by setting the environment variable `QT_BEARER_POLL_TIMEOUT` to -1.